# Cannot find module even though the cypress test runner is able to mount the component

Tags: cypress, vuejs3

I am trying to set up component tests with `cypress`, `vue3` and `vite`. With the Getting Started guide, I was able to successfully mount my component, however in my editor (vscode), it tells me that I cannot find the module or corresponding type declarations `ts(2307)`.

[image]

I have added the global styles file in `support/component.ts` and nothing else.

```js
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import "./commands";

// Import global styles
import "../../src/styles/style.scss";

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')

import { mount } from "cypress/vue";

// Augment the Cypress namespace to include type definitions for
// your custom command.
// Alternatively, can be defined in cypress/support/component.d.ts
// with a <reference path="./component" /> at the top of your spec.
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      mount: typeof mount;
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add("mount", mount);
```

How do I get rid of the linter warning?

Comment: the same problem spontaneously appeared today, and according to my git history, it's always been that way? maybe it's a bug in vscode

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Volar Takeover Mode fixed it for me. You do this by disabling VSCode's built-in TypeScript extension, then reloading VSCode.

[image]

Extensions panel > search for `@builtin typescript` > "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" > Right-Click > Disable (Workspace)

See Also https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode